# How do I style RelativeLayout from styles.xml - Android

Tags: android, styles, themes, android-relativelayout

I am trying to style a RelativeLayout from styles.xml because I have different themes and I am trying to change it's background. How do I do that?

I know that styling a ListView goes like this (for example):

```
    <style name="Theme_Day" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/def_actionbar_submenu_text</item>
    <item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/def_ListView</item>
    <item name="vpiTabPageIndicatorStyle">@style/CustomTabPageIndicator</item>
</style>

<style name="def_ListView" parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/listview_bg</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/def_listview_title_text</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@color/def_listview_itemdivider_bg</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">@dimen/listview_divider_height</item>
</style>
```

but when I try to find "android:relativeLayoutStyle" or parent="@android:style/Widget.RelativeLayout" I cant find anything..

How do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

This question has been asked before a long time ago, but you can always try like this:

```
<style name="RelativeLayoutStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget">
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">7dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/holo_green_dark</item>
</style>
```

Now you can do:

```
<RelativeLayout
    style="@style/RelativeLayoutStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    ...
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any parent just write

```
<style name="def_RelativeLayout">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/listview_bg</item>
</style>
```

and set it in your style attribute of every relative layout

Answer (score 1):

Create a drawable file and then set `android:background` with the `@drawable/layout_style` property.

For example, this drawable file is used to create a Google Card like design:

**background_card.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"
            android:dither="true">
            <corners android:radius="2dp"/>
            <solid android:color="#ccc" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:bottom="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"
            android:dither="true">
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
            <padding android:bottom="8dp"
                android:left="8dp"
                android:right="8dp"
                android:top="8dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

And from the layout XML file, you need to set the `android:background` property:

```
android:background="@drawable/backgorund_card"
```

_

```
<RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_id"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/backgorund_card" >
```